# hibernate search with a subset of entity and a string

Tags: hibernate-search

See we have a `class(entity) A` and `class(entity)` Category:

```
class A {
    private String title;
    private Category category;
}

class Category {
    .....
}
```

I want to apply hibernate search on the title and under one category, Any idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Field` on your *title* field, add `@IndexedEmbedded` on your *category* field, then also annotate the fields you want to search on in the *Category* type.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-indexing-associations

Comment: Thanks! I used must annotations and also solved the problem.